JupyterLab kernel connection issue after installing Python 3.11 on Ubuntu 20.04
I recently installed Python 3.11 on my Ubuntu 20.04 system alongside Python 3.8. After installing Python 3.11 using the appropriate method, I used pip3.11 to install JupyterLab. The installation was successful, but when I try to run a Jupyter Lab (.ipynb) file, I encounter an error indicating that JupyterLab cannot connect to the kernel.:
[W 2024-04-25 17:57:52.943 ServerApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/3eff6947-c100-41bd-a1cf-42ef3f5baf0c?1714055272927 (3385f741cc38459eb292354f81cbc452@127.0.0.1) 2.21ms referer=http://localhost:8888/lab/tree/Codes/WCR/Untitled1.ipynb
[W 2024-04-25 17:58:02.951 ServerApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/3eff6947-c100-41bd-a1cf-42ef3f5baf0c/channels?session_id=e942d7e8-ebe2-4ea9-a4af-72cff3451ca2 (127.0.0.1): Kernel does not exist: 3eff6947-c100-41bd-a1cf-42ef3f5baf0c
[W 2024-04-25 17:58:02.953 ServerApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/3eff6947-c100-41bd-a1cf-42ef3f5baf0c/channels?session_id=e942d7e8-ebe2-4ea9-a4af-72cff3451ca2 (3385f741cc38459eb292354f81cbc452@127.0.0.1) 3.15ms referer=None
[W 2024-04-25 17:58:02.959 ServerApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/3eff6947-c100-41bd-a1cf-42ef3f5baf0c?1714055282956 (127.0.0.1): Kernel does not exist: 3eff6947-c100-41bd-a1cf-42ef3f5baf0c
[W 2024-04-25 17:58:02.959 ServerApp] wrote error: 'Kernel does not exist: 3eff6947-c100-41bd-a1cf-42ef3f5baf0c'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/sina/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1790, in _execute
        result = await result
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/home/sina/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jupyter_server/auth/decorator.py", line 73, in inner
        return await out
               ^^^^^^^^^
      File "/home/sina/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jupyter_server/services/kernels/handlers.py", line 75, in get
        model = await ensure_async(km.kernel_model(kernel_id))
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/home/sina/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jupyter_server/services/kernels/kernelmanager.py", line 501, in kernel_model
        self._check_kernel_id(kernel_id)
      File "/home/sina/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jupyter_server/services/kernels/kernelmanager.py", line 532, in _check_kernel_id
        raise web.HTTPError(404, "Kernel does not exist: %s" % kernel_id)
    tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 404: Not Found (Kernel does not exist: 3eff6947-c100-41bd-a1cf-42ef3f5baf0c)
[W 2024-04-25 17:58:02.960 ServerApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/3eff6947-c100-41bd-a1cf-42ef3f5baf0c?1714055282956 (3385f741cc38459eb292354f81cbc452@127.0.0.1) 1.91ms referer=http://localhost:8888/lab/tree/Codes/WCR/Untitled1.ipynb
[W 2024-04-25 17:58:12.621 ServerApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from 3eff6947-c100-41bd-a1cf-42ef3f5baf0c
[I 2024-04-25 17:58:12.622 ServerApp] Connecting to kernel 3eff6947-c100-41bd-a1cf-42ef3f5baf0c.
[W 2024-04-25 17:58:12.625 ServerApp] 404 GET /api/kernels/3eff6947-c100-41bd-a1cf-42ef3f5baf0c/channels?session_id=e942d7e8-ebe2-4ea9-a4af-72cff3451ca2 (127.0.0.1): Kernel does not exist: 3eff6947-c100-41bd-a1cf-42ef3f5baf0c
^[[C[I 2024-04-25 17:58:35.436 ServerApp] Saving file at /Codes/WCR/Untitled1.ipynb

Im using Ubuntu 20.04 and python 3.11
